# Trying to remove a hyphen from string . The replace method is not working

Tags: c#

I have a 
 
`string myStringTitle= "Insurance Subsequent Action - Removing Coverage";`

I use the method

```
myStringTitle.replace("-", "");
```

and also

```
Regex.Replace(myStringTitle, @"[^-]", ""); <br>
```

none of them seems to work any reason why?. thanks

Comment: a) it is `Replace`, not `replace` b) it doesn't replace in place, it *returns* a new string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are immutable. `Replace()` will create a new string and you must assign the result to a variable. It does not modify the string in-place.

So, change your code as:

```
myStringTitle = myStringTitle.Replace("-", "");
```